# Multiple composite indexes with EF 6.2

Tags: c#, sql, .net, indexing, entity-framework-6

Having this entity and map (simplified):

```
public class Payment {
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }
    public string ExternalPaymentId { get; set; }
    public string PaymentId { get; set; }
    public Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>().HasKey(e => new { e.TenantId, e.Id },
    config => config.IsClustered(true));
modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>().HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId, e.ExternalPaymentId })
    .IsUnique(true);
modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>().HasIndex(e => new { e.TenantId, e.PaymentId })
    .IsUnique(true);
```

EF generates the following migration:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Payments",
    .............................
    .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.TenantId, t.Id })
    .Index(t => new { t.TenantId, t.PaymentId }, unique: true)
    .Index(t => t.ExternalPaymentId, unique: true, name: "IX_TenantId_ExternalPaymentId");
```

Why didn't it include `TenantId` column in the second index? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a currently open issue in EntityFramework github for your problem: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/460

There is a PR, not merged yet, to fix the issue https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/pull/534. And the expected release version is 6.3.0.

You might want to write the migration manually to workaround the issue at the moment.